# How to customize the size of callout for MKAnnotationView?

Tags: iphone, ios, size, mkannotationview, callout

I'm new to iOS.
I need to set the size of the callout 300 * 150, how can I do this?
[image: http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/57/1imgz.jpg]

Comment: i think you can use your own imageview instead of Default MKannotationview and add anything to it.

Comment: Could you explain me how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added subview with size I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the callout bubble adjusts according to the text it contains. If you set Title and subtitle as some long text, the callout will adjust according to it.